# Why am I not getting data sent from postman in JSON format?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, intellij-idea, postman

I want to modify an existing user object in the database (retrieved using its id) via a @RequestBody (Spring Boot). Unfortunately, my object is found, but all String values are replaced by a null type. When I display the data I'm supposed to receive, everything is null.

Model

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String email;

    @Column
    private String password;

    @Column
    private String role;

    @Column
    private double somme_dispo;
}
```

Controller

```
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.fan2foot.fan2foot.repository.UserRepository;
import com.fan2foot.fan2foot.service.UserService;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody;
import com.fan2foot.fan2foot.model.User;

@PutMapping("/update/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<User> update(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody User user)  {
    System.out.println(user.getName());
    System.out.println(user.getEmail());
    System.out.println(user.getPassword());
    System.out.println(user.getRole());
    User users = userService.updateUser(id, user);
    System.out.println(users.getName());
    System.out.println(users.getEmail());
    System.out.println(users.getPassword());
    System.out.println(users.getRole());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Service

```
public User updateUser(Long id, User user) {
    return userRepository.findById(id)
            .map(u -> {
                u.setName(user.getName());
                u.setEmail(user.getEmail());
                u.setPassword(user.getPassword());
                u.setRole(user.getRole());
                u.setSomme_dispo(user.getSomme_dispo());
                return userRepository.save(u);
            }).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("User non trouvé..."));
}
```

[Here is how I send data in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMF0C.png)

[Here is the result of the query execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tg2tK.jpg)

With another guy we inspected the model, controller, service and concluded that we have exactly the same code, his code works but mine doesn't

Comment: Can you replace the images with the code? just copy paste the code in code blocks.

Comment: Ok it's done !!

Comment: Have you checked your DB whether data updated or not ?

Comment: Data are update in the DB

Comment: The output shows that the `@RequestBody User user` gets filled with an instance of `User`, but all the fields are `null`. But the field names match the json, so this should work. At least I cannot see an obvious problem.

Comment: I agree on this fact, I've been on it since yesterday. The field name are create by Spring Boot in DB so it's the same

Comment: As you are telling db is updated. But in screenshot I see even in controller while you printing data, there is null also while receiving object from postman.

Comment: Yeah, is that my problem, I receive null from postman, so my user in DB updated to null

Comment: @Juu Can you post what are the import in controller ?

Comment: @AvijitBarua There it is

Comment: @Juu I found the problem may be. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the @RequestBody import,

I think this import making issue

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody;
```

Use this import

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your putMapping code with the following one:

```
@PutMapping(value = "/update/{id}", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

Post running the program please let us know the output of the spring application.

Comment: The output is the same, all values are null